# How to listen to AWS IOT Thing Shadow updates

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a THING and an APP connected together using AWS IOT, both using the [AWS IOT SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js).  THING has a temperature (`set_temp`) which can be set and a temperature sensor (`actual_temp`).

THING listens on the `$aws/things/THING_ID/shadow/updates/delta/` MQTT topic.  APP publishes on the `$aws/things/THING_ID/shadow/updates/` topic using the following message:

```
{
    "state": {
        "desired": {
            "set_temp": 38.7
        }
    }
}
```

This MQTT message propagates to the Thing Shadow and then through to the THING itself.  However, when the THING reports the following on the `$aws/things/THING_ID/shadow/updates/` topic:

```
{
    "state": {
        "reported": {
            "set_temp": 38.7,
            "actual_temp": 32.4
        }
    }
}
```

...  the Thing Shadow receives it, but it does not propagate the message to the APP.  This is fine for `set_temp`, since it does not really need to propagate back to the APP.  But when the `actual_temp` changes, it should propagate back to the APP, but it never does.

According to the [AWS IOT documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/thing-shadow-data-flow.html) this should work.  They even say to send include "`desired: null`" in the message from the THING.

How can you "listen" to the Thing Shadow without polling it?  Either I'm doing something wrong or AWS have a gaping hole in their IOT platform.

**Update (including actual code):**

***`App.js:`***

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
var name = 'THING_ID';

var app = awsIot.device({
    keyPath: '../../certs/private.pem.key',
    certPath: '../../certs/certificate.pem.crt',
    caPath: '../../certs/root-ca.pem.crt',
    clientId: name,
    region: 'ap-northeast-1'
});

app.subscribe('$aws/things/' + name + '/shadow/update/accepted');

app.on('message', function(topic, payload) {
    // THIS LINE OF CODE NEVER RUNS
    console.log('got message', topic, payload.toString());
});
```

***`Device.js:`***

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
var name = 'THING_ID';

var device = awsIot.device({
    keyPath: '../../certs/private.pem.key',
    certPath: '../../certs/certificate.pem.crt',
    caPath: '../../certs/root-ca.pem.crt',
    clientId: name,
    region: 'ap-northeast-1'
});

device.subscribe('$aws/things/' + name + '/shadow/update/delta');

device.on('message', function (topic, payload) {
    console.log('got message', topic, payload.toString());
});

// Publish state.reported every 1 second with changing temp
setInterval(function () {
    device.publish('$aws/things/' + name + '/shadow/update', JSON.stringify({
        'state': {
            'reported': {
                'actual_pool_temp': 20 + Math.random() * 10
            }
        }
    }));
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that because I was using the same `clientId` for the APP and the THING.  They shouldn't have the same `clientId`.  Below is the code I was using that contains the `clientId`.

```
var app = awsIot.device({
    keyPath: '../../certs/private.pem.key',
    certPath: '../../certs/certificate.pem.crt',
    caPath: '../../certs/root-ca.pem.crt',
    clientId: 'MY_ID',            // This needs to be different for all parties
    region: 'ap-southeast-2'
});
```

This was answered thanks to AWS Support, [here is the specific thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=762526).